# codeigniter pagination get url

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have a site developed in codeigniter and in a page I want to use pagination.
The problem is. my url now is smoething like that:

```
http://site/index.php/tee/view_tee/?id=2
```

This is my code into the controller:

```
    $data['tee'] = $this->Tee_model->getTeeByUserId($this->input->get('id', TRUE));
    $data['tee_like'] = $this->Tee_model->getLikeTeeByUserId($this->input->get('id', TRUE));
    $data['user'] = $this->User_model->getUserById($this->session->userdata('id'));

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = site_url().'/tee/view_tee/?id='.$this->input->get('id', TRUE);
    $config['total_rows'] = count($data['tee']);
    $config['per_page'] = 6;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

    if (count($_GET) > 0) $config['suffix'] = '?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
         $config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'].'?'.http_build_query($_GET);

    $data['page_links']=$this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $this->load->view('view_tee_view',$data);
```

With this code when I click into my pagination link I have this url:

```
http://site/index.php/tee/view_tee/?id=2/6?id=2
```

If I click again I have this:

```
http://site/index.php/tee/view_tee/?id=2/6?id=2/6?id=2
```

This is my html:

```
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
foreach($tee as $t){
   // I have three div per lines
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this...

```
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
```

remove this...

```
if (count($_GET) > 0) $config['suffix'] = '?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
     $config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'].'?'.http_build_query($_GET);
```

[EDIT] WORKING EXAMPLE

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['base_url'] = site_url().'/tee/view_tee/?id='.$this->input->get('id', TRUE);
$config['total_rows'] = 200;
$config['per_page'] = 6;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Comment: isn't sufficient not working, for example I have this link:site.com/index.php/tee/view_tee/?id=2&per_page=6

Comment: "isn't working" isn't helpful to debug anything... be specific about what the problem is. could you generate the pagination in the view? can you click page 1 2 ... 4 5 etc and get the URL to change?

Comment: try that working example, it proves that any problem isn't with the "pagination" part of the code. check that your total_rows is correct. check that you're using per_page to offset your search query properly.